# Selenium's waitForPageToLoad not reliable?

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium to verify google.com
First I type a Search query in the Search box, and click the Search button. 
The next page displays the Search results for the query.

I used

```
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("60000");
```

and then check that some elements on this page exist.
But I get a "ERROR: Command timed out" for the waitForPageToLoad command.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a mixed bag problem. You may want to give clickAndWait a try, but with the changes to asynchronous requests all over the web some of that has become unreliable. Some pages, even with the great google, don't return to a ready state and the script cannot tell the difference. You can, however, turn to waits (waitForElementPresent, waitForPageToLoad) and the problem should go away or at least be more manageable. Until it is addressed you may want to go into your google preferences and turn off Google Instant.

Comment: Does this mean in the 60seconds I am waiting, there are continuous asynchronous/AJAX events happening? The Search results page looks pretty simple, how can we tell if a page has AJAX elements on it?

Comment: Not necessarily. 

Occasionally, ajax requests don't typically update the browser. Some more interesting apps actually cause the browser to think its being updated and there may be issues with the response.

Comment: To tell if there are AJAX elements on a page, watch it. If anything is happening that does not require a page refresh it is an asynchronous request of some sort, typically AJAX, but it depends on the browser and if flash is involved.

Comment: We have some AJAX heavy applications that i am in charge of SQA and Automated testing and dealing with the AJAX calls with selenium/watir is a hell of a balancing act, and can depend upon a number of factors, including but not limited to browser, browser version and latency.